# Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:8000/issues/app.bundle.js”

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, bundle, mern

I have a MERN project. It uses "webpack": "^5.75.0" to proxy an express app "express": "^4.18.2"

Whenever I navigate to a URL that goes a level deep with a '/', index.html won't be able to find app.bundle.js as it tries to find app.bundle.js in that particular folder.

eg. **"http://127.0.0.1:8000/issues/app.bundle.js"** in here this app configuration tries to locate app.bundle.js in issues folder which is incorrect.

---

**[Project Folder structure (link to github)](https://github.com/jangir-ritik/issue-tracker)**

[image: folder structure]

---

[index.html](https://github.com/jangir-ritik/issue-tracker/blob/main/static/index.html)
:entry point to the app

```
<script 
  src="./app.bundle.js">
</script>
```

---

Webpack.config.js

```
import { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } from 'webpack-bundle-analyzer';
import path from 'path';

// const __dirname = path.dirname(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname);
const __dirname = path.resolve();

const config = {
  entry: './src/App.jsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static'),
    filename: 'app.bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
  ],
  devServer: {
    port: 8000,
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'static'),
    },
    proxy: {
      '/api/*': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000'
      },
    },
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  mode: 'development',
}

export default config;
```

---

Server.js

```
// const express = require("express")
// const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// const { validateIssue } = require('./issue')
const __dirname = path.resolve();


import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { MongoClient, ObjectId } from 'mongodb';
import Issue from './issue.js';
import SourceMapSupport from 'source-map-support'; 

SourceMapSupport.install();
const app = express();
// app.use(express.static('static'))
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//DATABASE 
// const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
const client = new MongoClient(URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

let db;

async function connect() {
    await client.connect();
    console.log('Connected to the database server')
    db = client.db('issuetracker');
    const collection = db.collection('issues');
    return 'done.'
}

// Connect to the database
connect()
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(3000, () => console.log('App started on port 3000'))
  })
  .catch(console.error)
  // .finally(() => client.close())


  // REST API ROUTEs
app.get('/api/issues', (req, res) => {
    const filter = {};
    if (req.query.status) filter.status = req.query.status;
    if (req.query.effort_lte || req.query.effort_gte) filter.effort = {};
    if (req.query.effort_lte) filter.effort.$lte = parseInt(req.query.effort_lte, 10);
    if (req.query.effort_gte) filter.effort.$gte = parseInt(req.query.effort_gte, 10);
    console.log(filter);
    db.collection('issues').find(filter).toArray().then(issues => {
      const metaData = { total_count: issues.length}
      res.json({_metaData: metaData, records: issues})
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      res.status(500).json({ message: `Internal server error: ${error}`})
    })
});

app.post('/api/issues', (req, res) => {
    const newIssue = req.body;
    newIssue.created = new Date();
    if (!newIssue.status)
        newIssue.status = "New";
    

    // THIS IS WHERE I AM CALLING THE ISSUE FUNCTION
    const err = Issue(newIssue)
    if (err) {
        res.status(422).json({message: `Invalid request: ${err}`});
        return;
    }
    db.collection('issues').insertOne(newIssue).then(result => 
      db.collection('issues').find({_id: result.insertedId}).limit(1).next()
      ).then(newIssue => {
        res.json(newIssue)
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({message: `Internal server error: ${error}`})
      }) 
})

app.get('/api/issues/:id', (req, res) => {
  let issueId;
  try {
    issueId = new ObjectId(req.params.id);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(422).json({ message: `Invalid issue ID format: ${error}`});
    return;
  }

  db.collection('issues').find({_id: issueId}).limit(1)
  .next()
  .then(issue => {
    if (!issue) res.status(404).json({ message: `No such issue: ${issueId}`});
    else res.json(issue);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: `Internal server error: ${error}`});
  });
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve('static/index.html'))
})
```

**It works correctly when I do not have a '/' in my url**. eg. http://127.0.0.1:8000/issues or http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts

but as soon as I put a '/', http://127.0.0.1:8000/issues/ or http://127.0.0.1:8000/issues/63f9e35faad2eb82a7bb8129

it gives me an error, "**Loading failed for the  with source “http://127.0.0.1:8000/issues/app.bundle.js”**."

i am not sure about creating a minimum working project so I've listed all the config files that I think are affecting the routing.
What am I doing wrong? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
<script src="/app.bundle.js"></script>
```

The difference: You had a `.` at the beginning of the path, which simply says: Get the file from the current folder of the html file the script tag is located in.

With the leading slash, as per this answer, you tell the browser to get the file always from the root.